# How to work with two Parse account in 'one' app

Tags: android, parse-platform

We are creating an Android launcher with several 'pre-installed' apps. These apps are actually part of the same code though to the user and from out perspective these apps are different logical units.

We work with Parse Core and would like to split the data into two different logical 'apps'. Can it be done?

We thought to call 'Parse.initialize' several times with different App & Client keys but then how should we proceed to report to different apps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced exactly the same issue a few months ago. Atleast, I was not developing a launcher. So, I'm posting my solution to the problem below.

---

***Note: You cannot do it with Parse SDK***

---

So the solution is to do it by having your app expose their own APIs. This has several advantages such as, your parse-apps could be owned by different accounts, while not violating the Parse terms of use.

### TL;DR

Create two different apps and expose the API's using cloud code. Use a REST client to transact data back and forth.

### Full Solution

The first step is to create two parse-apps, that you think suits individual needs of your launcher software. You can [generate express servers](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/building-parse-web-apps-with-the-express-web-framework/) for both the apps. Essentially, the result of this step is that, you will have two different apps with your own APIs to be consumed.

Now get rid of the Parse SDKs you might probably be using currently. Select a suitable REST client, in my case it was [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). Configure it such a way that it can consume different base-URLs for individual calls. The following is a Retrofit specific example.

**A Function that Returns a REST Adapter with a Base URL**

```
public FirstAppApi getFirstAppApi() {
    return new RestAdapter.Builder()
                          .setEndpoint("http://app-one.parseapp.com/")
                          .build()
                          .create(FirstAppApi.class);
}
```

In this example `FirstAppApi` is essentially a Retrofit interface. Similarly, you can create adapter for the second parse-app as well. Now, to do a data transaction, its just a matter of deciding which app you should use. See a few examples below.

```
// Get an author from the first Parse app
Author author = getFirstAppApi().getAuthorByName("Shakespeare");

// Get books of the author from the second Parse app
List<Book> books = getSecondAppApi().getBooksByAuthor(author);
```

A few things needs to be taken care in this implementation. The API is exposed publicly, eventhough the app name, and thus the base-url is known only to you. So, the API should be well secured when completed. You should double confirm with Parse guys that it does not violate their terms of use.

Comment: You don't need to have a server. You can use the REST API from your app.

Comment: @RaphaelRoyer-Rivard What `server` are you referring to?

Comment: You said "You can generate express servers for both the apps." but after you also say that you can use a REST client in your app. My bad

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to repackage jar-files of Parse SDK with [jarjar tool](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar).
Another way is to get [source code of Parse SDK](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android)(it is opensourced) and refactor it (change package name).

After you do it you can work with two Parse accounts using different classes:

```
com.parse.Parse.initialized();
com.parse2.Parse.initialized();
```

If you use Parse's offline storage only second option is available. But you also have to change database name for second Parse instanse (com.parse2.Parse). You need to change com/parse2/OfflineSQLiteOpenHelper.java

```
/** package */ class OfflineSQLiteOpenHelper extends ParseSQLiteOpenHelper {

  // ...

  /**
   * The SQLite Database name.
   */
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ParseOfflineStore2"; // <=====
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
```

Comment: While it is true that they have open sourced their SDKs, but I don't think this solution would work either. https://www.parse.com/questions/multiple-parse-instance-in-same-app

Comment: Your link is about iOS - I don't know does ios have similar to it or not. In java you can repackage jar and it will not have any common with original jar. You can use both in your code. I looked deeper in the Parse code and saw only one shared point - offline storage. To fix it just rename the DATABASE name.

Comment: Interesting. I would give it a try myself anyway.